# push event change from google calendar into my application

Tags: java, calendar, google-calendar-api, ical4j

I have my own application with calendar which can add/delete/edit events and it pushing change into google calendar. Is possible push events after change back? For example if I change event date in google calendar it will change event in my application too. I am using Java with iCal4j.

Comment: Just a side question: Is there a reason you do not use google's client libs? But I did not see a "push" there neither at first glance. I _guess_ you'll have to poll for changes but I am really not sure.

Comment: I want works with different calendars not only with google. Now my application can theoretically works with every calendar which iCal4j supports. But still only from my application to another calendar and not vice versa.